# Spanning Tree Portfast in JUNOS

Tags: juniper, spanning-tree

Can someone tell me what the Juniper JUNOS equivalent is for Cisco's spanning tree portfast command? My google-fu keeps leading me to long whitepapers on Spanning tree and not so much configuration examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Edge command, either by range or per port.

edit - [here](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/junos/junos95/swconfig-layer-2/conf-stp.html)'s a guide